# Удалить массив во вложенном массиве PHP

Tags: php

Только начал изучать PHP (да и в общем программирование) и вот столкнулся с такой задачкой. (Извините за оформление, впервые задаю вопрос.)
У меня есть вот такой массив:

```
$res = array(
   'n0' => array(
     '0' => array('VALUE' => '-', 'VALUE_TYPE' => 'WORK'),
     '1' => array('VALUE' => '+7 912 3631000', 'VALUE_TYPE' => 'WORK'),
     '2' => array('VALUE' => '+7 903 3419395', 'VALUE_TYPE' => 'WORK'),
     '3' => array('VALUE' => '+7 903 3419395', 'VALUE_TYPE' => 'WORK')
  ),
  'n1' => array(
      '0' => array('VALUE' => '-', 'VALUE_TYPE' => 'WORK'), 
      '1' => array('VALUE' => '-', 'VALUE_TYPE' => 'WORK'), 
      '2' => array('VALUE' => '+7 903 3419395', 'VALUE_TYPE' => 'WORK')
  ) 
  'n2' => array(
      '0' => array('VALUE' => '-', 'VALUE_TYPE' => 'WORK'), 
       '1' => array('VALUE' => '-', 'VALUE_TYPE' => 'WORK'), 
       '2' => array('VALUE' => NULL, 'VALUE_TYPE' => 'WORK')
   )
)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне получить вот такой массив:

```
$res = array(
    'n0' => array(
        '1' => array('VALUE' => '+7 912 3631000', 'VALUE_TYPE' => 'WORK'),
        '2' => array('VALUE' => '+7 903 3419395', 'VALUE_TYPE' => 'WORK'),
        '3' => array('VALUE' => '+7 903 3419395', 'VALUE_TYPE' => 'WORK')),
    'n1' => array( 
        '2' => array('VALUE' => '+7 903 3419395', 'VALUE_TYPE' => 'WORK')) 
    
)
```

Нужно удалить массивы где `'VALUE' => '-'` или `'VALUE' => NULL`.

Comment: там концовка `n2` корректна у вас? несколько иная структуруа

Comment: Извините, ошибся. Исправил

Answer (score 2):

Если вы начинающий то вам подойдет этот вариант

```
    $res = array(
        'n0' => array(
            '0' => array('VALUE' => '-', 'VALUE_TYPE' => 'WORK'),
            '1' => array('VALUE' => '+7 912 3631000', 'VALUE_TYPE' => 'WORK'),
            '2' => array('VALUE' => '+7 903 3419395', 'VALUE_TYPE' => 'WORK'),
            '3' => array('VALUE' => '+7 903 3419395', 'VALUE_TYPE' => 'WORK')
        ),
        'n1' => array(
            '0' => array('VALUE' => '-', 'VALUE_TYPE' => 'WORK'),
            '1' => array('VALUE' => '-', 'VALUE_TYPE' => 'WORK'),
            '2' => array('VALUE' => '+7 903 3419395', 'VALUE_TYPE' => 'WORK')
        ) ,
      'n2' => array(
            '0' => array('VALUE' => '-', 'VALUE_TYPE' => 'WORK'),
            '1' => array('VALUE' => '-', 'VALUE_TYPE' => 'WORK'),
            '2' => array('VALUE' => NULL, 'VALUE_TYPE' => 'WORK')
        )
    );
$result = [];
foreach($res as $k => $re) {
    foreach($re as $k1 => $r) {
        if(!in_array($r['VALUE'], ['-', '_']) and $r['VALUE']) {
            $result[$k][$k1] = $r;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможно, лучше добавить null в массив in_array вместо `and $r['VALUE']`

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо использовать функции [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php) и [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php)

```
$res = array_filter(array_map(function($entry) {
    return array_filter($entry, function($item) {
        return $item['VALUE'] !== '-' && $item['VALUE'] !== null;
    });
}, $res), function($mapped) {
    return !empty($mapped);
});
```

array_map создаст новый массив из элементов старого
array_filter добавит в новый массив только элементы, которые соответствуют условию

Comment: работает, но ```n2``` остается пустым. Не удаляется полностью.

Comment: дополнил ответ. поверх еще раз применяем array_filter, чтобы отсечь пустые элементы